# count the number of times "x" appears by row when "x" is a factor

Tags: r

How would you count the number of times "B" or "C" appear by row when columns are factors? I get how you could use `rowSums()` if numeric, but I'm not seeing how to count factor levels.

Have:

```
df <- data.frame(v1=factor(c("A", "A", "A", "B")),
                 v2=factor(c("A", "B", "B", "B")),
                 v3=factor(c("C", "A", "B", "B")))
```

Want:

```
# 1 1 2 3
```

**Update**

`rowSums()` failed for my actual use case because my data frame had date columns. Here is a better toy example:

```
df2 <- data.frame(v1=factor(c("A", "A", "A", "B")),
                  v2=factor(c("A", "B", "B", "B")),
                  v3=factor(c("C", "A", "B", "B")),
                  v4=as.Date("1998-12-17"))
```

Comment: A simplified version could be `rowSums(df == "C" | df == "B")`. An uglier but more general could be ```colSums(apply(df, 1, `%in%`, LETTERS[2:3]))```

Comment: Please read `?rowSums` about argument `x`: "an array of two or more dimensions, containing numeric, complex, integer **or logical values**. Also recommended reading: `?TRUE`: "Logical vectors are coerced to integer vectors in contexts where a numerical value is required".

Comment: ok, thanks. I think my actual use case complained about your approach, @DavidArenburg, because I have some date columns in the data frame.

Comment: @Frank, so I need to limit to factor (or string in my actual case) columns then run `rowSums`...`cols <- sapply(df, is.factor) | sapply(df, is.character)`?

Comment: @EricGreen Sorry, my suggestion was wrong. You could do as David suggested, excluding the date rows, yes: `rowSums( df[, -date_col_nums]=="B"|df[,-date_col_nums]=="C" )`

Comment: so something like the following seems to work: `rowSums(df[sapply(df, is.factor) | sapply(df, is.character)]=="B" | df[sapply(df, is.factor) | sapply(df, is.character)]=="C")`. easier way to define `date_col_nums` in @Frank's example?

Comment: How you identify the columns you want to skip or include in the sum depends on your data and preference. I guess there are many ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From @DavidArenburg:

```
rowSums(df == "C" | df == "B")
```

This works on the original `df` example. My actual use case had date columns in the data frame, so it failed. A modified approach based on an idea from @Frank:

```
rowSums(df2[sapply(df2, is.factor) | sapply(df2, is.character)]=="B" | df2[sapply(df2, is.factor) | sapply(df2, is.character)]=="C", na.rm=T)
```

Probably a cleaner way to code this, but it works:

```
#[1] 1 1 2 3
```